# Intersections of a Line & a Plane in 3d-Space

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Given the line [x,y,z]:(1,-3,2)+t [-2,4,7] find planes to satisfy the following conditions:
A plane which is intersected by the line at the point (3, -7, -5)

I am unsure what to do with this, if I should form it into parameters or turn it into a scalar equation? Any advice or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First note that there are infinitely many planes that fit that description, and you're told to find one. That means you need to make a choice. One  choice could be "the plane that contains the point $(3,-7,-5)$ and is _perpendicular_ to the line". There's no reason that that plane is a better solution than any other plane, but it will give you a valid answer, and a concrete place to start.

Comment: There are 3 equations and one $t$ to solve, it is over determined, so cannot be solved. You need to change either the second coordinate set or the third set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the line [x,y,z]:(1,-3,2)+t [-2,4,7] find planes to satisfy the following conditions: A plane which is intersected by the line at the point (3, -7, -5)

A generic plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies the ecuation:

$Ax + By + Cz = D$ where $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}$

you want in addition that when $t=-1$ the point $(3,-7,-5)$ is in the plane, that is:

$3A - 7B - 5C = D$

So every plane that satisfies what is asken is of the form

$Ax + By + Cz = 3A - 7B - 5C$